# Error when trying to run security examples in wsf/php 2.1

Tags: java, apache-axis

After installing wsf/php 2.1 using

```
./configure --enable-libxml2 --disable-savan
make 
sudo make install
```

All Examples work except for security examples... and I get this error logged in apache error.log:

```
/usr/lib/php5/xxx/wsf.so: undefined symbol: rampart_context_create
```

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 and PHP 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.3 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Dec 13 2011 18:37:10)

What could be the error?

Comment: The problem seems to be the ubuntu version 11.10, it is working with ubuntu 11.04 with apache and php compiled from sources

Comment: possible duplicate of [WSO2 WSF error / rampart_context_create](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135411/wso2-wsf-error-rampart-context-create)

Comment: I see that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135411/wso2-wsf-error-rampart-context-create is an exact duplicate of my question

Answer (score 7):

After a lot of searching I found many people with the same problem but no one with an answer. As I am sure a lot of people have been having the same problem I dug into the problem on my own and found a solution. It is a problem with the version of gcc in 11.10 and 12.04.

I was able to get it to work by doing

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.4
```

and then configuring wsf/php by running

```
./configure CC=gcc-4.4
```

Follow the rest of the normal installation steps and it should work.

You can also check the wsf.so library to see if it has the rampart libs linked in it by doing

```
ldd /usr/lib/php5/20090626/wsf.so
```

I hope this helps everyone out there!